# callbackQuery telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Никак не могу разобраться с `callbackquery` в `Telegram Bot API`.
Одним из требований является `id` - уникальный идентификатор запроса, откуда его взять?

```
$callbackquery=array(array("id"=>"","from"=>"$user","data"=>"$inbreply2"));
$inlinekeyb=array(array(array("text"=>"принять","callback_data"=>"$callbackquery")));
$inlineresp=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inlinekeyb);
$inbreply=json_encode($inlineresp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Объект вида [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) возвращается боту (например при использовании метода [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates)) после того как пользователь нажал CallbackButton. При этом в объекте в поле `data` будет то, что Вы указали в параметре `callback_data` в массиве описывающем [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton)

Например в reply_markup мы передаем такой массив:

```
$arMarkup = [
    'inline_keyboard' => [
        [
            ['text' => 'test_1','callback_data' => '1'],
            ['text' => 'test_2','callback_data' => '2'],
        ]
    ]
];

//не забываем преобразовать в JSON
$replyMarkup = json_encode($arMarkup);
```

Пользователь в клиенте нажимает кнопку с надписью `test_1` и затем ответ с `CallbackQuery` отправляется на веб-хук или мы сами должны получить его через метод `getUpdates`

Например мы получаем сообщения через `getUpdates`, тогда вызвав метод, мы получаем JSON вида:

```
"{"ok":true,"result":
    [
        {
            "update_id":xxxxxxxxxx,
            "callback_query":
            {
                "id":"xxxxxxxxxxx",
                "from":
                {
                    "id":xxxxxxxxx,
                    "first_name":"xxxxxxx",
                    "last_name":"xxxxxxx",
                    "username":"xxxxxxxxx",
                    "language_code":"ru"
                },
                "message":
                {
                    "message_id":xxxx,
                    "from":
                    {
                        "id":xxxxxxxxx,
                        "first_name":"xxxxxxxx",
                        "username":"xxxxxxx"
                    },
                    "chat":
                    {
                        "id":xxxxxxxx,
                        "first_name":"xxxxxxx",
                        "last_name":"xxxxxxxx",
                        "username":"xxxxxxx",
                        "type":"private"
                    },
                    "date":1499854111,
                    "text":"test"
                },
                "chat_instance":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "data":"1"
            }
        }
    ]
}"
```

Далее можно обработать этот `CallbackQuery` и например отправить пользователю сообщение в зависимости от того что содержится в поле `data`

Совсем простой пример:

```
<?php
$bot = new TelegramBot();
$arUpdates = $bot->getUpdates();

if (!empty($arUpdates['result'])) { 
    foreach ($arUpdates['result'] as $arResult) {
        if (array_key_exists('callback_query',$arResult)) {

            $userId = $arResult['callback_query']['from']['id']; 

            if ($arResult['callback_query']['data'] == 1) {
                $bot->sendMessage($userId, 'Its ok!');
            } else {
                $bot->sendMessage($userId, 'Its not ok!');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: можете более раскрыть про объект CallbackQuery? и куда должен везти callback_data?

Comment: callback_data никуда не ведет, это просто строка длинной до 64 байт, которая возвращается боту после нажатия на кнопку. Чуть обновил ответ, надеюсь поможет понять=)